# NativeScript Change Selected Tab in TabView

Tags: typescript, navigation, nativescript

I can't seem to find how to navigate to a different tab in a tabView via code in a partial View (each tab is in a child folder with its own html/ts/js/css file).
The specific use case in this scenario is when a user clicks on an item in a list it should switch to a different tab passing the context (item data) with it.

I can change the selected tab in the parent file using this:

```
export function nav()
{
    pageData.set("tabIndex", 2);
}
```

However I do not know how to set it from a child document or how to pass data to a different partial view

I'm using partial views to create the tabs, with the partial views just being stacklayouts so my page with the tab-view looks like the following:

```
<TabView selectedIndex="{{tabIndex}}" >
 <TabView.items>
  <TabViewItem title="Drop Sequence">
    <TabViewItem.view>
      <DropSequence:DropSequence />
    </TabViewItem.view>
  </TabViewItem>

  <TabViewItem title="Edit Order" >
    <TabViewItem.view>
      <EditOrder:EditOrder />
    </TabViewItem.view>
  </TabViewItem>
```

Answer (score 3):

I usually use NativeScript-Angular and  to my understanding it is an Angular way of doing it.

First, add an id of the TabView TabView id="tabview1" and then write something like:

```
var tabview1 = page.getViewById("tabview1");
tabview1.selectedIndex = 1;
```

Comment: I have to cast it to the corresponding Type, otherwise the cli will recognize tabview1 as Viewbase and print an error. 

So my code looked like this. 

var tabview1 = <TabView> this._page.getViewById("tabview1");
tabview1.selectedIndex = 1;